# pip not able to install zipline on OS X

Tags: python, macos, numpy, zipline

I have been trying to install zipline on OSX 10.11.2.

The pip install fails with this error:

```
$ pip install zipline
Collecting zipline
  Using cached zipline-0.8.3-cp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting six==1.9.0 (from zipline)
  Using cached six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil==2.4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from zipline)
Collecting patsy==0.4.0 (from zipline)
  Using cached patsy-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numexpr==2.4.3 (from zipline)
  Using cached numexpr-2.4.3-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting cyordereddict==0.2.2 (from zipline)
  Using cached cyordereddict-0.2.2.tar.gz
Collecting bcolz==0.10.0 (from zipline)
  Using cached bcolz-0.10.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    * Found Cython 0.23.4 package installed.
    .. **ERROR:: You need numpy 1.7 or greater to run bcolz!**

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sj/py2gp2555d15c757mxtpwmn80000gn/T/pip-build-se3cq5/bcolz
```

I checked my numpy version, it's 1.10.2:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.10.2'
```

I tried installing bcolz separately (and it installed successfully) but that didn't solve the problem.

```
$ pip install -I zipline
```

didn't work either.

Any ideas about what I should do to install zipline?

**EDIT**: I ran `pip install bcolz` and the version installed was 0.12.1:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bcolz$ cat version.py
# coding: utf-8
# file generated by setuptools_scm
# don't change, don't track in version control
version = '0.12.1'
```

Comment: When you say you successfully installed bcolz separately "but that didn't solve the problem", there would presumably be a different error message. What did that message say?

Comment: to identify package versions, you can run too `pip freeze`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question in case anyone had the same issue. I ended up installing zipline using Anacaonda instead and it worked out alright. The package changes were:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    bcolz:         1.0.0-py27_0     
    click:         6.6-py27_0       
    contextlib2:   0.4.0-py27_0     
    cyordereddict: 0.2.2-py27_0     
    logbook:       0.12.5-py27_0    
    zipline:       0.9.0-np19py27_0 

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    bottleneck:    1.0.0-np110py27_0  --> 1.0.0-np19py27_0 
    numba:         0.24.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.24.0-np19py27_0
    patsy:         0.4.0-np110py27_0  --> 0.4.0-np19py27_0 
    scipy:         0.17.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.17.0-np19py27_0
    statsmodels:   0.6.1-np110py27_0  --> 0.6.1-np19py27_0 

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    anaconda:      4.0.0-np110py27_0  --> custom-py27_0    
    astropy:       1.1.2-np110py27_0  --> 1.0.4-np19py27_0 
    h5py:          2.5.0-np110py27_4  --> 2.5.0-np19py27_3 
    matplotlib:    1.5.1-np110py27_0  --> 1.4.3-np19py27_3 
    numexpr:       2.5-np110py27_0    --> 2.4.6-np19py27_0 
    numpy:         1.10.4-py27_0      --> 1.9.3-py27_1     
    pandas:        0.18.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.16.2-np19py27_0
    pytables:      3.2.2-np110py27_1  --> 3.2.2-np19py27_0 
    scikit-image:  0.12.3-np110py27_0 --> 0.11.3-np19py27_0
    scikit-learn:  0.17.1-np110py27_0 --> 0.16.1-np19py27_0
```

Answer (score 1):

One information you do not provide is the version of `bcolz` you tried to install separately. If it is not the 0.10.0, as zipline requirements file pins the version of `bcolz` (see [here](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/blob/master/etc/requirements.txt#L44)), if a newer version of bcolz has been installed (it will be the case if you just run `pip install bcolz`), the first thing the next install of `zipline` will do is to downgrade your `bcolz` installed version.

If you succeed in installing the version `0.10.0` of `bcolz`, the outputted error must be different and it would help to have it!

[EDIT]: so by running `pip install bcolz==0.10.0`, you're able to reproduce the same issue. It appears that due to a broken version comparison, bcolz, in its 0.10.0 version will be unable to work with version of numpy starting from 1.10. The only solution is then to downgrade numpy, and ping zipline developers so that they bump the used version of bcolz.

Comment: I seemed to have 0.12.1 installed from the pip install of bcolz. I have now removed it. When I try `pip install bcolz==0.10.0`, I get, 
`Collecting bcolz==0.10.0
  Using cached bcolz-0.10.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    * Found Cython 0.23.4 package installed.
    .. ERROR:: You need numpy 1.7 or greater to run bcolz!
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sj/py2gp2555d15c757mxtpwmn80000gn/T/pip-build-rI0ecp/bcolz`

Comment: So you reproduce the same error. Which is a good first step! By investigating the issue tracker of bcolz, i found this: https://github.com/Blosc/bcolz/issues/275. So until zipline does not update its bcolz requirement, your only options would be to downgrade your version of numpy.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I removed numpy 1.10.2 and am trying to install 1.7. Some issues with that but I'll try to get that done.

Answer (score -1):

Have been having exactly the same problem. Just to add to the answer. This is the terminal command that has worked for me : `conda install -c quantopian zipline=1.0.2`